# when Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE is call?

Tags: actionscript-3, stagevideo

I have this code :

```
addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
```

when is this event called ? I'm working on a [example project of StageVideo](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSe9ecd9e6b89aefd2-68d5ef8f12cc8511f6c-7ffe.html) but it isn't easy. I'm working on flash pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE` is called whenever `addChild()` or `addChildAt()` is called.

In order to make sure that the stage and parent are available within the object that is being added to the stage that you add the listener of `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE` within the object's constructor and then when that object is added to the stage, its `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE` listener will be fired and the stage and parent of that object will be available.

### Example:

```
package {

import flash.display.Sprite;

public class Main extends Sprite {

    public function Main() {
        var textField:ChildTextField = new ChildTextField();
        textField.text = "Hello StackOverflow";
        addChild(textField);
    }
}
}

import flash.events.Event;
import flash.text.TextField;

class ChildTextField extends TextField {
    public function ChildTextField() {
        trace("(Stage (Before addChild):" + stage);
        trace("ChildTextField Parent (Before addChild): " + this.parent);
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initWhenAddedToStage);
    }

    function initWhenAddedToStage(e:Event):void {
        trace("Stage (After addChild): " + stage);
        trace("ChildTextField (After addChild): " + this.parent);
    }
}
```

### Output:

```
[trace] (Stage (Before addChild):null
[trace] ChildTextField Parent (Before addChild): null
[trace] Stage (After addChild): [object Stage]
[trace] ChildTextField (After addChild): [object Main]
```

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by its name, the [`addedToStage`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#event:addedToStage) event is

> Dispatched when a display object is added to the on stage display list, either directly or through the addition of a sub tree in which the display object is contained. The following methods trigger this event: DisplayObjectContainer.addChild(), DisplayObjectContainer.addChildAt().

Hope that can help.